# Return all columns specified in the join conditions (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have two data frames and I join them using dplyr's `left_join`:

```
test <- data.frame(numbers = c(1, 2, 3), letters = c("a", "b", "c"))
test2 <- data.frame(numbers2 = c(1, 2), letters2 = c("a", NA))

left_join(test, test2, by = c("numbers" = "numbers2"))
```

I get a data frame like this:

```
  numbers letters letters2
1       1       a        a
2       2       b     <NA>
3       3       c     <NA>
```

I don't see the `numbers2` column from the join condition. Is this by design? I would like to get this column so I can see the records from `test2` that returned `NA` (i.e. the ones that did not match the join condition). I can't rely on `letters2` to do that because it is not a key.

How do I see this column & should dplyr create an argument in their join functions to do this?

Comment: `numbers` and `numbers2` are the same as you joined on them. As `test2` has no record for `numbers2 = 3` it returns `NA` and the other `NA` is there because you have one in your data (column `letters2` in `test2`); 
No problem in the code or the design

Comment: @Titolondon based on the above data frame and nothing else, I am unable to answer the question "how many numbers from test2 are also in test". If you `?left_join` it says this: _return all rows from x, and all columns from x and y. Rows in x with no match in y will have NA values in the new columns. If there are multiple matches between x and y, all combinations of the matches are returned._

Comment: I think your result correspond exactly to the explication of `?left_join`. You obtained all column of x and y and all rows. However, you have no duplicates in your key columns, so no multiple match. You cannot answer your question because of existing `NA` in `test2` (you would have only one `NA` otherwise) but you have one line more than `test` so it  kind of the answer your looking for.

Comment: So I acknowledge the way it might work internally is to (for want of a better word) coalesce `numbers` and `numbers2` into one output, but it isn't doing what it says: it is returning all non-key columns from x and all non-key columns from y and a key, which is 3 columns, not 4. To get the information I need, I'd need to amend `test2` like this; `test2 <- data.frame(numbers2 = c(1, 2), letters2 = c("a", NA), join_check = 1)`. It's the same behaviour in `merge()` as well; it just feels crappy.

Answer (score 0):

yh it is by design, `numbers2` are already contained in `numbers` in the resulting dataframe. you do see it in letters2 if the original `test2` does not contain NA. If you really want it, then duplicate it in `test2` as something and then rename back in the resulting one.

Comment: I just find it strange that it is contradicted in [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf) - return all rows from x, and all columns from x and y